# highcharts spline with multiple series update every few seconds

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts, spline

I am trying to get a spline chart with 2 series that updates every few seconds. I have spent lots of time searching through various examples and I can get many different things to work but NOT this. I just cant seem to find an example that is exactly what I am trying to do out there.

I have the following json that is returned via ajax:

```
[{"name":"Test1","data":[[1415567095000,2117]]},{"name":"Test2","data":[[1415567095000,2414]]}]
```

Below is what I have for the chart definition. This is a slightly modified example that I found but I just cant figure out how to get this to work. I know that it should not be that complex and since I am new to javascript, I suspect it will be something simple that I just don't see. I know that I need to define multiple series and then perform addPoint with a shift but I cant seem to get it to work.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

    var options = {
            chart: {
                renderTo: 'container',
                type: 'spline',
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Dynamic RPS'
            },
            subtitle: {
                text: 'US East'
            },
            xAxis: {
               type: 'datetime',
            },
            yAxis: {
                min: 0,
                title: {
                    text: 'RPS '
                }
            },
            plotOptions: {
                column: {
                    pointPadding: 0.2,
                    borderWidth: 0
                }
            },
            series: [{}]
    };
setInterval(function() {

    $.getJSON('test.php', function(data) {
           options.series = data;
        var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
    });
}, 20000);

});
</script>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated !!

Comment: Does the ajax call return a single point each time?  Or data with all points?

Comment: it returns the same  2 points each time. So I have a proper graph with 2 series but it does not add (push) the new points to the series. I cant figure out how to implement the addPoint and define multiple series..

Comment: I don't understand, if it returns the same two points each time, where do the "new points" come from?

Comment: sorry , what I mean is that it calls the php script and will render a chart with 2 series and 2 data points. ( not the same points) What I am trying to accomplish is something like this http://www.highcharts.com/demo/dynamic-update

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your `test.php` will return a single new point on each call, I'd code it like this:

```
  var chart = null;
  function callAjax(){
    $.getJSON('test.php', function(data) {
      if (chart === null){ // first call, create the chart
        options.series = data;
        chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
      } else {
        var seriesOneNewPoint = data[0].data[0]; // subsequent calls, just get the point and add it
        var seriesTwoNewPoint = data[1].data[0];
        chart.series[0].addPoint(seriesOneNewPoint, false, false); // first false is don't redraw until both series are updated
        chart.series[1].addPoint(seriesTwoNewPoint, true, false); // second false is don't shift
      }
      setTimeout(callAjax, 20000);  // queue up next ajax call
    });
  }
  callAjax();
```

Here's an [example](http://plnkr.co/edit/3hrOFphMJbuRjH9AJG0d?p=preview).  Note, it just draws the same point over and over again.

Comment: very close but I am trying to maintain the last data points called and create a graph that shows a line of points which a new one is added to the array every time it updates. Like this line I referenced from highcarts demos.. (http://www.highcharts.com/demo/dynamic-update) Maybe this requires another approach??

Comment: just to be clear the php script us call an api that give average 1sec response times for the last one second.. So each poll will receive 2 new single data points that I need to add to the existing points already displayed on the chart..

Comment: sorry you are 100% correct in your approach and I messed it up by not grabbing the ,ine that defined chart = null. Now that I have that , this works exactly as I needed it to . THanks so much for the help as this has been a real pain to get working!!